# How to make sure child object is valid while saving parent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

let say that I have two class

```
class User
  attr_accessible :name

  has_one :address

  validates :name, :presence => true
  validates_associated :address
end

class Address
  attr_accessible :country, :user_id

  belongs_to :user

  validates :country, :presence => true
  validates :user, :presence => true
end
```

Now when i try to create invalid `Address` then it fails(which is good)

```
a = Address.new
a.valid?  #=> false
```

But when i build User with invalid `Address` then it pass(which is bad)

```
u = User.first
u.build_address

u.valid?  #=> true
u.save    #=> true
```

Due to this `User` has `Address` with country => nil.

How can i tell Rails to not save `Address` if its invalid?

FIXED: I fixed this by adding follow line to the code. Thank you everyone.

```
validates_associated :address, :if => :address
```

Comment: What does your build_address do? Nevermind, you could also check the presence of the address by `validates_presence_of :address` because if address is not present, the `validates_associated` will not fail

Comment: Iralution build is rails method

Answer (score 1):

```
class User
  attr_accessible :name

  has_one :address, :validate => true

  validates :name, :presence => true
  validates_associated :address
```

end

Comment: I will try this and let you know. Give me 1 minute.

Comment: Same behavior when you use `u.create_address!` ?

Comment: Iralution, yes i get same behavior when using `u.create_address!`

Answer (score 0):

You need to also validate that an `Address` is actually present for `User`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :address, :associated => true, :presence => true
end
```

With that in place, I get:

```
>> u = User.first
=> #<User id: 1, name: "Bob", created_at: "2013-10-09 15:17:21", updated_at: "2013-10-09 15:17:21">
>> u.build_address
=> #<Address id: nil, user_id: 1, country: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
>> u.valid?
=> false
>> u.errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fe1d6919b18 @base=#<User id: 1, name: "Bob", created_at: "2013-10-09 15:17:21", updated_at: "2013-10-09 15:17:21">, @messages={:address=>["is invalid"]}>
>> u.address.errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fe1d69197a8 @base=#<Address id: nil, user_id: 1, country: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:country=>["can't be blank"]}>
```

Comment: That works fine but Now you cant create a `User` without having `Address`

Comment: fixed it by using ````validates_associated :address, :if => :address````