# Advanced ruby on rails models and validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In general, I have a website which needs to have complex registration process. And in that registration process I need to include 4 tables from database.

Now... I cannot validate one by one model and to enter 4 of them in database. Is there a way to make common points of all those tables in one model?

Let's say:
`User` model has columns: `username, name`, etc.
`Package` model has: `type, account_number`
etc

And in registration process I need to include username, name, account_number and to validate them. How to do that?

Comment: have a look at [nested forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and some [existing questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19273698/how-to-make-sure-child-object-is-valid-while-saving-parent). the idea is that you can deny saving a parent object if child objects are invalid.

Comment: Also have a look at delegation: http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your model structure, this is just speculation, but here goes:

--

**Virtual Attributes**

In your `User` model, you can use [`attr_accessor`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370960/what-is-attr-accessor-in-ruby) to create a set of `virtual attributes` - which basically mean you can create a series of `setter / getter` methods in your `User` model.

Although I don't think this will help you directly, it should give you an idea as to how you can create single-model validation:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :new, :values, :to, :validate
    validates, :new, :values, :to, :validate, presence: true
end
```

This will allow you to create the attributes in the `User` model - and although they won't be saved, you can then use them to validate against

---

**`attr_accessor`**

To give you a quick overview of this method, you first need to remember that Rails is just a collection of `modules` and `classes`.

This means that every `model` you load is just a `class` which has been populated with a series of `getter` / `setter` methods. These methods are defined by `ActiveRecord` from your data table columns, and are why you can call `@user.attribute`

The magic is that if you use `attr_accessor`, you'll basically create your own attributes in your `User` model - which won't be saved in the database, but will be treated like the other attributes your objects have, allowing you to validate them

Answer (score 1):

Because your registration process seems to be complex, I would go even futher as virtual attributes and use Form Objects

[7 Patterns to Refactor Fat ActiveRecord Models](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/)

[LA Ruby Conference 2013 Refactoring Fat Models](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5yX6ADjyqyE#t=18m43s)

[ActiveModel Form Objects](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/activemodel-form-objects)

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you multistep registration. You shouldn't create 4 models only because your view pages needs it. You should:

1. remove validation from `User` model and add validation on each form
2. create 4 different forms (for example extends by `ActiveModel` or user gem `reform`)
3. add validation to each form
4. after `form.valid?` save part of user info to `@user` object

Thats all.